# Is there any simple PHP/MySQL shopping cart?

Tags: php, mysql, shopping-cart

I need to use some shopping cart for selling "Scripts" online. 
Is there any simple and clean PHP/MySQL shopping cart integrated with [PayPal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PayPal) that can be used free?

The feature that I require is, a link will be dynamically generated for certain days and sent to the user who paid so that they can instantly download the script as soon as they purchased it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None is better than [Magento](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magento), just make sure to download and install the free one.

Answer (score 0):

[Zen Cart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zen_Cart). It's to easy customize compared to Magento. Easy and free download and installation.